# ProviderIncompatibleException was unhandled by user code

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have just got the latest code from SVN and I got the above error when I logged into my application.  The exception message was:

> An error occurred while getting provider information from the
>   database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect
>   connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure
>   that the connection string is correct.

The inner exception says:

> The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error
>   during connection initialization process before login. Possible causes
>   include the following:  the client tried to connect to an unsupported
>   version of SQL Server; the server was too busy to accept new
>   connections; or there was a resource limitation (insufficient memory
>   or maximum allowed connections) on the server. (provider: Shared
>   Memory Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.

The issue is, none of these suggestions seem like the cause.  Any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to love the solution to this.  I restarted my machine and it works fine now. :o).